# Grails 2.4.4: createCriteria: how to use the sum of a date and integer in order?

Tags: hibernate, grails, createcriteria

Domain Class:

```
class Record {
    Date date
    Integer days
}
```

Code:

```
def record.createCriteria().list {
    order( "DATE_ADD( date, INTERVAL days DAY )", "asc" )
}
```

Question:

Obviously this doesn't work, but I need to know if there is a way to order by date + days using createCriteria.

Thank you :)

Comment: I don't think this will be possible using `createCriteria` as the `order` node is really just a wrapper around the `org.hibernate.criterion.Order` class, which doesn't have this capability.  I'm sure there is a SQL only solution but I don't believe there is an easier way through GORM.

Comment: You can use @Formula mapping and place your expression in a field (let's name it sortOrder) of Record and later just use the field in order()

Answer (score 0):

Like what @StanislavL said, you can use [formula](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#derivedProperties)

```
Date dateWithAdditionalDays

static mapping = {
        dateWithAdditionalDays formula: 'DATE_ADD( date, INTERVAL days DAY )'
}

def record.createCriteria().list {
    order('dateWithAdditionalDays')
}
```

Comment: According to your link, `formula` is only for use under the `discriminator` mapping and its purpose is to : "**an SQL expression that is executed to evaluate the type of class.**"

Comment: I found the proper documentation: [Derived Properties](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/GORM.html#derivedProperties)

Comment: So this is a great idea, but fails with:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'this_.INTERVAL this_.days this_.DAY ) as formula0_0_ from record this_ order by ' at line 1

Comment: Thanks @tylerwal.  havoc74, is your formula working in your mySql database?